Name That Plant
I got this from an old office that was being demolished. It was on a desk and initially five inches. It's since grown but I don't know what it is.
It's still in a vase and the roots at the crown of the plant have grown so I'll have to break the vase to pull them out.
I want to know what it is so I know what soil it needs once it's free from the vase and I'm also tired of calling it "plant". It looks like some kind of dracaena but I'm uncertain.
Any help is appreciated. 

Please add a photo (it's the button that looks like the moon over two mountains once you [edit] your post).

If it lives in water, regular potting soil will do.
